# evaluate integral with fractional exponents

Tags: integration

Can someone please help me integrating this?

$$\displaystyle \int \frac{w\mathrm dw}{(5-3w)^{2/3}}$$

---

I tried substituting $5-3w = u$ and $-3\mathrm dw = \mathrm du$.
So $w = (u-5)/3$ and then we have
$$\int\frac{u-5}{3u^{2/3}}\mathrm du$$

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :**

$$\int \frac{u-5}{3u^{2/3}} \,du =\frac{1}{3}\left( \int u^{1/3} \,du-5\int u^{-2/3} \,du\right)$$

Comment: so my final answer would then lead to {[(5-3w)^4/3]/4}-[5(5-3w)^1/3]+C?

Comment: @sheila $\int x^n \,dx =x^{n+1}/(n+1) + C$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{w}{(5-3w)^{2/3}} = \dfrac{5-(5-3w)}{3(5-3w)^{2/3}}=\dfrac{5}{3}\cdot (5-3w)^{-2/3}-\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot (5-3w)^{1/3}$

Comment: so my final answer would then lead to {[(5-3w)^4/3]/4}-[5(5-3w)^1/3]+C?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int \frac{w}{(5-3w)^{2/3}}dw \;
$$

Let $u=5-3w$, then $w=\frac{5-u}{3}$ and $dw = \frac{-du}{3}$.  Using these substitutions we get:

$$
\int \frac{\frac{5-u}{3}}{u^{2/3}}du \;\; = \frac{5}{3}\int \frac{du}{u^{2/3}}-\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{du}{u^{1/3}}
$$